# Which is better, praying in jamaah but not focus or praying alone but focus?

Tags: salat, ramadan, taraweeh

Friends i want to ask the best opinion about my story, yesterday i prayed on the mosque near my house because i heard there will be some adventages if i pray in jamaah but surprisingly the mosque was so crowded and there was so many child goofing off that made there pretty hot and noisy , i can't focus on my shalat but if i did it alone on my room i'll be 99% focus. So my question is what's the best suggestion for me ? 
I hope you guys help me quick in case of ramdhan is going to be over

Comment: For men, Farz is always more beneficial to be prayed in Jama'ah. It is imp to do wudu with Khushu and pray as it the last prayer you may be ever praying. If possible speak to your local imam to see if he can help you bring khushu in your salaat. Salaam!

Answer (score 1):

### Nafl (Sunnah) prayers including Tarawih

It's better to do it at home.
**for Tarawih**
It's better at home on one condition that your absence will not stop the prayer in Masjid, so if other people are praying in Masjid it's ok but if you are the only one with the imam and if you do not go the prayer in Masjid will be stopped then you need to go to Masjid.
It's also better if you pray at home with intention "Niyyah" to Make Jamaah with your Family so you encourage them to pray "Tarawih".

### Obligatory Prayers

It's better and you get much more Ajr for doing it in Masjid.

### Last word

evaluate where you benefit more, for example:

- Do you read as much Quran as the imam in Masjid?
- Do you do as much and good Duaa as Imam in Masjid

Some people read Quran and make Duaa even better!

Comment: thanks a lot ya akhi , may Allah will always bless yoiu, Assalamualaika...,

Comment: If you find the answer useful, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the check next to the answer, and also voting it up.